# Calculating Running Balance column

Tags: r, data.table

I need help with R and the data below. For each date there is a value  (column A) and i need to calculate the Balance column which is total less each lines value in column A. 406 is the total of column A.

I currently have this data in a data.table.

```
Dates        A        Balance
                      406.00
30/12/2016   100.00   306.00 
31/03/2017   101.00   205.00 
30/06/2017   102.00   103.00 
29/09/2017   103.00   -
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please `dput(yourData)` - put the result in your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44459113/edit

Answer (score 1):

You could use a loop and just do the calculation manually, excluding the last row.

```
data <- data.frame(A = c(NA, 100, 101, 102, 103), Balance = c(406, NA, NA, NA, NA))
for (i in 1:(nrow(data) - 1)) {
    data$Balance[i + 1] <- data$Balance[i] - data$A[i + 1]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`data$Balance <- sum(data$A)-data$A`

You can create the balance columb by summing all of A then substracting by the vector A.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the required result

```
# Create dataframe
df <- data.frame(Dates = c("30/12/2016","31/03/2017","30/06/2017","29/09/2017"),
                 A = c(100.00, 101.00, 102.00, 103.00))

# Create empty Balance column
df$Balance <- NA

# Insert total balance to top of dataframe
df <- rbind(c(NA,0,sum(df$A)), df)

# Get the running balance
df$Balance <- sum(df$A) - cumsum(df$A)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to point out the function `cumsum` was made for this. After inverting the data frame...:

```
df <- df[seq( nrow(df), 1 ),]
df
       Dates     A Balance
       <chr> <dbl>   <chr>
1 29/09/2017   103       -
2 30/06/2017   102  103.00
3 31/03/2017   101  205.00
4 30/12/2016   100  306.00
5       <NA>    NA  406.00

cumsum(df$A)
[1] 103 205 306 406  NA
```